# Populate JComboBox with data from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I have a table called 'supplier' which has two columns 'suppID' and 'suppName'.

I want to pull the data from suppName and fill it into a JComboBox in a way that will keep the contents up to date, meaning if a new row inserted or deleted the JComboBox will be showing the data exactly as it is stored in the table at the time of opening it

```
        addStock.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,addStockPanel,"Add new stock", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            try{
                //Connect to DB
                Connection conn = CatalogueDB.getConnection();
                //Prepare statement to pull data
                Statement pull = conn.createStatement();


            } catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error adding supplier");}
            //Finish by printing a message to say the insert has worked.
            finally{
                System.out.println("Insert Completed.");
```

The only idea that comes to mind with my level of knowledge is to do a select statement from the table then store that in a string, but as I insert data I would constantly have to add more strings to accommodate the extra information.

Comment: Please restate your problem in a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (understandable) manner. Are you trying to say that you want to keep the contents of the combobox current by updating its list of suppliers every time you add or remove a supplier? You really don't need extra SQL operations for that, if that's the case.

Comment: @MarsAtomic yes, I need the JComboBox to stay up to date with the MySQL table.
I wasn't sure how I would be able to do it in such a way that would keep it updated.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to populate your JComboBox with the contents of the MySQL table when the GUI is created, or actually update the JComboBox every n seconds with what may or may not be changed in the MySQL table?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc this is all going to happen within a JOptionPane which opens when a button is pressed in my main GUI so, I assumed that because the SQL commands are within that buttons action listener that it would update every time the button is pressed and the JOptionPane is opened but, perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: No, your comment is not wrong.  Your question wasn't clear.  Yes, you'll get the current state of the SQL table when you SELECT as a part of the actionListener.  I'd separate the SQL into a separate class and use an application model of plain Java classes to hold the information from the SQL table.  The application model then provides the information for the JComboBox.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you created your combobox since you neglected to post the code, but in short, to keep the combobox updated every time you add a new supplier, you can use the following logic (actual implementation is up to you):

In your try statement (where you are actually attempting to add a new supplier to your table), follow the execution of the SQL statement with something like:

```
try
{
    //Connect to DB
    Connection conn = CatalogueDB.getConnection();
    //Prepare statement to push new supplier data
    Statement push = conn.createStatement();

    // adds new supplier name
    model.addElement(<name of supplier>);
    // notifies combobox that the underlying model has changed
    // box will be repainted automatically
    model.fireContentsChanged();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    // other handling as necessary
}
```

where [`model`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) is the model used for your `JComboBox`, and obviously, the name of the supplier is obtained from whatever variable stores the name of the new supplier you're trying to add.

If an exception prevents the supplier from being added, the part where you add the supplier's name to the combobox will not run, since control passes immediately to the `catch` portion of your try/catch.

There is no point in running an extraneous select statement to repopulate your combobox after successfully inserting a new supplier when you already have all the data you need.

Comment: Don't invoke `model.fireContentsChanged()`. It is the job of the model to invoked that method so all views can be notified of the change.